# Не работает jquery в Visual Studio 2017

Tags: jquery, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Есть проект asp.net core 2.2 созданный в visual studio 2017 15.9 (шаблон Веб приложение (модель-представление-контроллер)). Первоначально все работало, но ссылки на библиотеки были на внешний cdnjn:

```
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"
crossorigin="anonymous" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=">
</script>
```

Соответственно без интернета скрипт не работал. Для управление был добавлен libman.json. Ссылки стали вида:

```
<script src="/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
```

Но на странице перестал работать JS (библиотеки по указанному пути есть). Под отладкой в chrome ошибок нет, но и на представлении нет результата работы скрипта.

При создании нового проекта, все тоже самое. Такое подозрение что изменились настройки самой IDE. Попробовал сбросить настройки у Visual Studio, на настройки по умолчанию, но это не помогло.

Comment: Ошибки в консоли браузера есть? jquery в панели Network присутствует?

Comment: @br3t ошибок нет

Comment: Попробуйте добавить какой-нибудь тестовый скрипт `alert(!!window.jQuery)`